# How old is Nick Fury?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, nick-fury

What is Nick Fury's approximate age at various story intervals in the MCU?

I guess his *exact* birth date & age isn't important, but plus or minus a few years would be good to know. Given that the younger Nick Fury was shown in *Captain Marvel* and seemed to be more-or-less mid-career at that time, knowing his age would establish if we're likely to see even younger versions of him in action at SHIELD in future films.

Or for that matter, what the extent of his career might be in the future, assuming (hoping?) that somehow the end of *Avengers: Infinity War* turns out to be impermanent.

It also gives a sense of his physical capabilities (barring the superhuman). He is quite a commanding presence but that could mask some age-related limitations, for instance.

---

Note - I'm not asking the same thing as [Does Nick Fury age in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167362/does-nick-fury-age-in-the-marvel-cinematic-universe); that question is asking about whether he is aging physically, not how old he is in years since birth.

Comment: “I guess his exact birth date & age isn't important” — you're not gonna even send him a *card???*

Comment: @PaulD.Waite ok I just posted a question asking for his address ;)

Comment: In Iron Man 2, Tony says "Clearly you knew my dad better than I did," to which Nick replies "As a matter of fact, I did. He was one of the founding members of S.H.I.E.L.D." This suggests that Nick was around way back when S.H.I.E.L.D. was founded, back in the 40s. In the comics, Nick Fury was indeed around back then, he was one of the leaders of the Howling Commandos that Captain America also led.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## He was born on the 4th July 1950

We see this from this screenshot of his badge when he shows it to the officer at PEGASUS and gets the finger print on it.

[image: Fury's security badge]
<sub>*Note: The image isn't great quality so will add a better one when I can.*</sub>

That would put him as 44/45 during the events of *Captain Marvel* as that takes place in 1995.

---

His birthdate and age are deliberately hidden in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* according to [Film School Rejects](https://filmschoolrejects.com/37-things-we-learned-from-the-captain-america-the-winter-soldier-commentary-1b778b1b97ec/) but this too is unsourced as to the reasons why.

> Because they couldn’t show Nick Fury’s birth and death dates on his tombstone, the directors needed to fill that space, so they chose the Ezekiel 25:17 quote from Pulp Fiction. Nicely done.

[image: Fury’s gravestone]

Comment: I remember Sgt Fury and his Howling Commandos fighting Nazis in the 1960's comics.... obviously the MCU has a different view  on this

Comment: @DannyMcG It would be a bit difficult for Fury to still be physically active in the time the MCU currently takes place if he were that old and didn't have any Kree blood like Carol Danvers or be put in suspended animation like Steve Rogers and Bucky to keep him spry.

Comment: @DannyMcG I'm not sure, but I was under the impression that the current Nick Fury, director of SHIELD, was (at least on some continuity or other) supposed to be the *son* of Sgt. Fury of Howling Commandos fame. This would, at least, explain why they seem to look somewhat different.

Comment: @Admiral Jota. I found this online ...  It is eventually revealed that Fury takes a special medication called the Infinity Formula that halted his aging and allows him to be active despite being nearly a century old

Comment: @DannyMcG It looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Fury_Jr. confirms *both* of our recollections!

Comment: There was a comic where Nick Fury Jr. (Samuel L. Jackson look-alike) teamed up with Nick Fury (the original) by following a time traveler who went to the 1960's to kill Barack Obama as a kid.